# What is difference in RuntimeExecutionMode and ExecutionMode

Tags: apache-flink

I'm learning apache flink. when I read code of StreamExecutionEnvironment,I found it that there have two class about ExecutionMode, that is RuntimeExecutionMode and ExecutionMode. and I found that we always talk about RuntimeExecutionMode as ExecutionMode, but what is the actually ExecutionMode?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutionMode` is a historical class that only defined the shuffling behavior how data should be send to the next operator.

However, this is not enough for efficient batch processing. A true batch mode needs settings for various runtime components:

- schedule mode
- shuffle mode
- incremental updates

The true unification of the API happened in Flink 1.12. You can find more information in the [corresponding design document of FLIP-134](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-134%3A+Batch+execution+for+the+DataStream+API). Long story short: a class name for expressing the execution mode for the DataStream API was already taken, so the community decided for `RuntimeExecutionMode`. This enum sets various flags under hood for each Flink runtime component.